# Is it possible to apply prototype of an Object inside a function closure only?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function test(){
    String.prototype.to_selector=function(a){return "#"+a;}
    return "asd".to_selector();
}
```

I want `"asd".to_selector();` not working outside the function. How to do it? Or is it necessary?

Comment: Why would you possibly want to?  Just define a "to_selector" function normally and call it

Comment: I am a ruby person and I want a really object way to reuse it in many functions that use .to_selector(). Sorry to state the problem wrongly and I think @Sergi had found the my actual need of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test(){
    String.prototype.to_selector=function(a){return "#"+a;}
    var o = "asd".to_selector();
    delete String.prototype.to_selector;
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible, and in your example it's not really useful I'd say. Why not just use:

```
function test(){
    var to_selector = function(a){return "#"+a;};
    return to_selector("asd");
}
```

If you assign a prototype method for a native Object (`String` here), it's assigned for all subsequent calls to that Object.

You *can* assign a method directly to a genuine `String` Object but again I don't really see any use cases for that:

```
var test = function(a){
    var str = new String(a);
    str.to_selector = function(){return "#"+this;}
    return str.to_selector();
}
alert(test('asd')); //=> '#asd'
alert('bla'.to_selector()); //=> error
```

Comment: Whenever you make an object based on another object the original objects prototype is inherited by the new one. This [article on understanding JavaScript prototypes](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) might help.

Comment: @Useless Code: shouldn't this comment address the question itself? I think I understand the javascript prototype to a reasonable extent.

Comment: @Kooilinc Maybe so; it wasn't directed at you just adding it to the info in your post since it was very similar to the answer I was going to post.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible by modifying `String` prototype, since this would modify all the instances of String that you create after this function is executed.

I don't see the need of having a method for a native object that only works inside a specific function scope. What's the use case? You can always add a static method to the `String` object or a instance method to the `String` prototype (not a good practice, mind you) and only use it inside `test`.

You can also create a new object that you can use for that purpose, although you lose the elegance of calling `to_selector` directly from a string declaration:

```
var string2 = function(str) {
    this.str = str;
};

string2.prototype = {
    to_selector: function() {
        return '#' + this.str;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return this.str;
    }
};

function test(){
    asd = new string2("asd");
    return asd.to_selector();
}
```

But again, I can't see how this would be convenient at all.

Comment: wow .... you I ask the wrong question , but you gave me the answer I need! Awesome .... thanks

Comment: +1 for "I can't see how this would be convenient at all" Please program into a language and stop writing Ruby/Java/C/etc in js.